# How to use hive's explode() function for complex struct?

Tags: hive

My hive table looks like this :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sample(id STRING,products STRUCT<urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<url:STRING>>,product_names:ARRAY<STRUCT<name:STRING>>,user:ARRAY<STRUCT<user_id:STRING>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION ‘/user/input/sample’;
```

Is there any way to explode the products field, so that it should store the url,name,user_id into three different columns ?

Can anyone please suggest me out regarding the same ....

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to explode the your three arrays as follow

```
select url, product_name, user_id from sample
lateral VIEW explode(products.urls) A as url
lateral VIEW explode(products.product_names) B as product_name
lateral VIEW explode(products.user) C as user_id

;
```